# Why alignment is 16 bytes on 64 bit architecture?

Tags: c, x86-64, memory-alignment

```
(gdb) disas foo
Dump of assembler code for function foo:
0x00000000004004a8 <foo+0>: push   %rbp
0x00000000004004a9 <foo+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000000004004ac <foo+4>: mov    0x13c(%rip),%eax        # 0x4005ee <__dso_handle+30>
0x00000000004004b2 <foo+10>:    mov    %eax,-0x10(%rbp)
0x00000000004004b5 <foo+13>:    lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
0x00000000004004b9 <foo+17>:    add    $0x18,%rax
0x00000000004004bd <foo+21>:    mov    %rax,%rdx
0x00000000004004c0 <foo+24>:    mov    $0x400498,%eax
0x00000000004004c5 <foo+29>:    mov    %eax,(%rdx)
0x00000000004004c7 <foo+31>:    leaveq 
0x00000000004004c8 <foo+32>:    retq   
(gdb) l foo
8   void foo() {
9       char overme[4] = "WOW";
10      *(int*)(overme+24) = (int)bad;
11  }
```

Why not just 8 bytes?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49391001), although the code example is mostly unrelated to alignment, just some version of GCC's choice of where to put things in the red zone with optimization disabled.  In a test case that involves 2 different kinds of UB (strict aliasing violation and out-of-bounds array access).  So tells us very little.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

gcc is not "assigning" this space to the variable. Rather, the x86_64 abi requires the stack pointer to always be 16-byte-aligned at function calls, in case the callee uses vectorized SSE math. It's a really stupid and wasteful requirement (the callee should ensure the alignment if it needs it), but that's the standard, and gcc follows the standard. You can fix it with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=3` (8 byte alignment, the minimum for 64-bit).

Comment: @R,The register size is 8 bytes,why does it 16 bytes alignment?

Comment: Can you elaborate about the `vectorized SSE math`?

Comment: Apparently many SSE instructions either crash, do the wrong thing, or do it very slowly (not sure which) if given misaligned addresses. They work on 128 bits at a time, either single 128-bit floating point values or a vector of many smaller integer or floating point values, so the proper alignment is 16.

Comment: You don't want to turn it off. Some random optimized function will sooner or later use an xmm register and try to copy it on the stack at which point you'll segfault.

Answer (score 1):

It is 8 bytes, not 16.  The LEA instruction doesn't show anything alignment related, -0x10 is just an offset applied to the value of the RBP register.  Probably to generate the address of a small local array.  If the code generator uses any SIMD instructions then 16 could be relevant.  None of which is visible in a two-liner question.

Comment: @Hans Passant,I've updated with code,and `mov    %eax,-0x10(%rbp)` is assigning 16 bytes for `char overme[4]`

Comment: No, the EAX register stores 4 bytes.  It is copying the "WOW" string which just happens to be 4 bytes long as well.  I guessed the "small local array" correctly.  You'll get very different code when you make the string longer.  The code is otherwise UB.

Comment: @Hans Passant,can you elaborate why that "small local array" needs 16 bytes,not 8 bytes,if alignment is 8 bytes?

Comment: No idea, gcc often gobbles stack bytes.  It also isn't making space for array by adjusting rsp.  Try turning off the code optimizer to get something less RSA encrypted.  What is the point of this?  Are you trying to stomp the stack on purpose?

Comment: @Hans Passant,it's already compiled with optimizer off ,`gcc -O0 xxx`. Yes,I'm trying to stomp the stack,but don't understand why `overme` is assigned 16 bytes...

Comment: I've suspected -fstack-protector, but code doesn't look like this