# Difference in data alignment in struct vs parameter?

Tags: assembly, alignment, nasm, x86-64, calling-convention

Given the following code:

```
typedef struct tagRECT {
  int left;
  int top;
  int right;
  int bottom;
} RECT;

extern int Func(RECT *a, int b, char *c, int d, char e, long f, int g, int h, int i, int j);

int main() {

}

void gui() {
    RECT x = {4, 5, 6, 7};
    Func(&x, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
}
```

This is the assembly generated gcc x86_64 presumably on linux (I used [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/)).

```
main:
  mov eax, 0
  ret
gui:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 16
  ; RECT x assignment
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-16], 4
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 5
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 6
  mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 7

  ; parameters
  lea rax, [rbp-16]
  push 9
  push 8
  push 7
  push 6
  mov r9d, 5
  mov r8d, 4
  mov ecx, 3
  mov edx, 0
  mov esi, 1
  mov rdi, rax
  call Func
  add rsp, 32
  nop
  leave
  ret
```

It can be seen that the `int` in the struct are aligned by 4 bytes. But the last 4 parameters to the function, all `int` are `push`d to the stack which means they were aligned by 8 bytes. Why this inconsistency?

Comment: Have you read [the ABI document](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) for amd64 Linux?  It explains exactly how arguments to functions works.

Comment: @fuz yes I just read it and it does mention that parameters are to be 8 byte aligned but I still don't understand why struct is not..

Comment: Intuitively, because this way, compilers can simply push registers on the stack. Only 8 bytes can be pushed at a time on amd64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stack slots are 8 bytes in x86-64 calling conventions like the x86-64 System V calling convention you're using, because 32-bit push/pop is impossible, and to make it easier to [keep it 16-byte aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-system-v-amd64-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment).  See [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6) (it also covers function-calling conventions, as well as system-calling conventions.  [Where is the x86-64 System V ABI documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented).

`mov` works just fine, though, so it would have been a valid design to make 4 bytes the minimum unit for stack args.  (Unlike x86-16 where SP-relative addressing modes were impossible).  **But unless you introduce padding rules, then you could have misaligned 8-byte args.**  So giving every arg at least 8-byte alignment was probably part of the motivation.  (Although there are padding rules to guarantee that `__m128` args have 16-byte alignment, and `__m256` have 32-byte, etc.  And presumably also for over-aligned structs, like `struct { alignas(64) char b[256]; };`.

Only 4-byte slots would break more easily for functions without prototypes, and maybe make variadic functions more complex, but x86-64 System V already passes larger objects by value on the stack, so a stack arg may take more than one 8-byte "stack slot".

(Unlike Windows x64 which passes by hidden reference so every arg is exactly one stack slot.  It even reserves 32 bytes of shadow space so a variadic function can spill its register args into the shadow space and create a full array of all the args.)