# Alignment in 64bit machine is not 8 Bytes

Tags: c, compilation, cpu-architecture

I am trying to find out alignment on my 64bit machine(Win10 on Intel iCore7). I thought of this experiment:

```
void check_alignment(char c1, char c2 )
{
   printf("delta=%d\n", (int)&c2 - (int)&c1); // prints 4 instead of 8
}

void main(){
    check_alignment('a','b');
}
```

I was expecting **`delta=8`**. Since it's 64bit machine **`char c1`** and **`char c2`** should be stored on multiples of 8. Isn't that right?

Even if we assume compiler has done optimization to have them stored in less space, why not just store them back to back **`delta=1`**? Why 4 byte alignment?

I repeated the above experiment with **`float`** types, and still gives **`delta=4`**

```
void check_alignment(float f1, float f2 )
{
   printf("delta=%d\n", (int)&c2 - (int)&c1); // prints 4
}

void main(){
    check_alignment(1.0,1.1);
}
```

Comment: It is very possible that the arguments were passed via registers and the compiler was required to create temporary variables with automatic storage duration in order to satisfy the requirements of the address-of operator. In short, this has nothing to do with alighment.

Comment: Post the code that calls `check_alignment()`.  A [mcve]

Comment: "Since it's 64bit machine char c1 and char c2 should be stored on multiples of 8. Isn't that right? "  No, it is not right.  The compiler is at liberty to do whatever it wants, as long as the resulting program produces results that are compliant what what the C standard dictates.

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour. You are not allowed to subtract two pointers which don't point into (or exactly past) the same scalar or array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine the greatest fundamental alignment in your C implementation, use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%zd bytes\n", _Alignof(max_align_t));
}
```

To determine the alignment requirement of any particular type, replace `max_align_t` above with that type.

Alignment is not purely a function of the processor or other hardware. Hardware might support aligned or unaligned accesses with different performance effects, and some instructions might support unaligned access while others do not. A particular C implementation might choose to require or not require certain alignment in combination with choosing to use or not use various instructions. Additionally, on some hardware, whether unaligned access is supported is configurable by the operating system.

Comment: The OP might be interested to know that if you pass so many args that the calling convention doesn't have registers for them, the Windows x64 calling convention (like x86-64 System V) will pass them in 8-byte stack slots. (4 byte minimum alignment for stack args would have been a valid choice, too.  [Difference in data alignment in struct vs parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51564190)).  `max_align_t` doesn't tell you anything about the calling convention, but it's normal for the minimum stack alignment to be large enough to get `max_align_t` alignment without an extra `and` instruction.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, if your platform is 64-bit, then why are you casting your pointer values to `int`? Is `int` 64-bit wide on your platform? If not, your subtraction is likely to produce a meaningless result. Use `intptr_t` or `ptrdiff_t` for that purpose, not `int`.

Secondly, in a typical implementation a 1-byte type will typically be aligned at 1-byte boundary, regardless of whether your platform is 64-bit or not. To see a 8-byte alignment you'd need a 8-byte type. And in order to see how it is aligned you have to inspect the physical value of the address (i.e. whether it is divisible by 1, 2, 4, 8 etc.), not analyze how far apart two variables are spaced.

Thirdly, how far apart `c1` and `c2` are in memory has little to do with alignment requirements of `char` type. It is determined by how `char` values are passed (or stored locally) on your platform. In your case they are apparently allocated 4-byte storage cells each. That's perfectly fine. Nobody every promised you that two unrelated objects with 1-byte alignment will be packed next to each other as tightly as possible.

If you want to determine alignment by measuring how far from each other two objects are stored, declare an array. Do not try to measure the distance between two independent objects - this is meaningless.

Comment: I measured how far they are apart because they are passed as arguments of a function, so they will be placed immediately after each other in the function stack. That makes sure they are not located in random location in memory.

Comment: @Learner: No, they won't be. Almost nobody uses "stack" to pass scalar arguments anymore. Most likely they would be passed in CPU registers, without involving any "stack" at all. The only reason your parameter got stored locally is that you applied `&` operator to them. This forced the compiler to store them (on the "stack"). And it stored them 4 bytes apart. But even if "stack" was used to pass the arguments, there's still nothing to prevent the compiler from passing them 4 bytes apart. There's no requirement to pack them tightly.

Comment: What would be a correct way? I used `long`, and still `delta=4`. It must be at least 8.

Comment: @Learner: Where did you get this? `long` is at least 4, not 8. `long long` is at least 8.

Comment: @Learner: `(int)(&c2 - &c1)` would have been safer but still risky (e.g. after inlining, `c1` and `c2` might be far apart).  But `(unsigned)&c2 - (unsigned)&c1` would definitely avoid UB, because unsigned overflow is defined as wrapping around.  The low bytes of a subtraction result doesn't depend on the high bytes of the input, so it's ok to throw them away early if you want to assume that your objects are nearby.

Comment: @ant: on Windows x64, those two function args will be passed in RCX and RDX (so actually CL and DL for 1 byte integers).  The compiler has to spill them to give them an address.  (Or imagine spilling them, if the addresses are only subtracted.)  x86-64 System V would be similar, but in RDI and RSI (actually dil / sil).