# AT&T gcc assembly moving char value to register as an arg for puts

Tags: assembly, x86-64, puts

I'm loading string in rcx and moving rcx + 8bytes and padding with zeros and store in %r8

%r8 will contain 0x72, 72 is the ascii for the letter "r".
Using movq to move value of r8 into rdi which makes rdi 0x72. However on call puts i get sigsev, cannot access memory at 0x72. Why can't I do this?

```
        .data
string:    .asciz    "Hello world!"
.global main 
.text 

main: 
    leaq   string, %rcx
    movq $4, %rax 
    movzbq 4(%rcx,%rax,1), %r8 
    movq %r8, %rdi
    call puts
```

Comment: puts takes a `char*` pointer arg, and you passed `0x72` as the address.  Maybe you're looking for `call putchar` which takes a `char` by value.

Comment: Hint: in C, what is the difference between `puts("r")` and `puts('r')`, and why does the first one work while the second does not?

Comment: You also have a problem with stack alignment.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-the-x86-64-amd64-system-v-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment/49397524#49397524

Comment: Thank you, makes sense!