# Trying to understand the gcc assembly output for printf()

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to learn how to understand assembly code so I've been studying the assembly output of GCC for some stupid programs. One of them was nothing but `int i = 0;`, the code of which I more or less fully understand now (the biggest struggle was understanding the GAS directives strewn about). Anyway, I went a step forward and added `printf("%d\n", i);` to see if I could understand that and suddenly the code is much more chaotic.

```
    .file   "helloworld.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .p2align 4
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    subq    $8, %rsp
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rsi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $1, %edi
    call    __printf_chk@PLT
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Gentoo 10.2.0-r3 p4) 10.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I'm compiling this with `gcc -S -O3 -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` to remove the `.cfi` directives, however `-O2` produces the same code so `-O3` is overkill. My understanding of assembly is quite limited but it seems to me like the compiler is doing a lot of unneccessary stuff here. Why subtract and then add 8 to `rsp`? Why is it performing so many `xor`s? There's only one variable. What is `movl    $1, %edi` doing? I thought maybe the compiler was doing something stupid in an attempt to optimize but as I said, it's not optimizing beyond `-O2`, also it performs all of these operations even at `-O1`. To be honest I don't understand the unoptimized code at all so I assume it's inefficient.

The only thing that comes to mind is that the call to `printf` uses these registers, otherwise they are unused and serve no purpose. Is that actually the case? If so, how is it possible to tell?

Thanks in advance. I'm reading a book on compiler design at the moment and I've read most of the GCC manual (I read the whole chapter on optimization) and I've read some introductory x86_64 asm material, if somebody could point me toward some other resources (besides the Intel x86 manual) for learning more I would also appreciate that.

Comment: This assembly doesn't seem to match the code you supposedly compiled. This is what I'd expect to see if you called `printf(1, "%d\n")`, and judging from godbolt, this is in fact very close to the assembly you get when calling `printf(1, "%d\n")`.

Comment: @Aplet123 This is the code: ```#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
 int i = 0;
 printf("%d\n", i);
}```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for lots of useful links.  The [ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented) is likely to be of particular interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the compiler that you are using it looks like printf(...) is mapped to __printf_chk(1, ...)

To understand the code, [you need to understand the parameter passing conventions for the platform (part of the ABI)](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse378/10au/sections/Section1_recap.pdf).  Once you know that up to 4 params are passed in %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, you can understand most of what is going on:

```
subq    $8, %rsp             ; allocate 8 bytes of stack
xorl    %edx, %edx           ; i = 0 ; put it in the 3rd parameter for __printf_chk
leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rsi     ; 2nd parameter for __printf_chk.  The: "%d\n"
xorl    %eax, %eax           ; 0 variadic fp params
movl    $1, %edi             ; 1st parameter for __printf_chk
call    __printf_chk@PLT     ; call the runtime loader wrapper for __printf_chk
xorl    %eax, %eax           ; return 0 from main
addq    $8, %rsp             ; deallocate 8 bytes of stack.
ret
```

Nate points out in the comments that section 3.5.7 in the [ABI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) explains the %eax = 0 (no floating point variadic parameters.)

Comment: I see! Reading up on Linux x86 calling conventions was on my reading list, I guess it was more important than I realized. Re: __printf_chk, the compiler calls printf() directly at ```-O0``` but uses ```__printf_chk``` when optimizations are turned on. Didn't occur to me that the other 0 could be the return value, my main() function has an imlicit return value and in the case of ```main() { int i = 0; }``` there was no return value, only a return statement. Now it makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For a variadic function like `printf`, `%al` is required to be set to the number of vector (`%xmm`) registers being used to pass floating-point parameters.  See 3.5.7 of the [ABI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) Here there are no floating-point parameters being passed, so `%al` must be zero.  The compiler zeroes out all of `%eax` (which in fact zeros all of `%rax`) because why not (maybe to avoid some partial register dependencies).

Comment: Also, the `sub $8, %rsp` isn't really to allocate 8 bytes of stack per se (the function doesn't use that space for anything), but rather to ensure [stack alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-the-x86-64-amd64-system-v-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment) as required by the ABI (see 3.2.2).

Comment: @NateEldredge, isn't 8 byte stack alignment required?  If so, subtracting another 8 bytes doesn't do anything for alignment.  Isn't there implicit usage of this stack storage by __printf_chk (if it calls anything, isn't the return address saved in the stack storage allocated by the caller?)

Comment: No, the required alignment is 16 bytes.  The stack was aligned to 16 bytes before `main` was called, the `call` instruction to transfer control to `main` pushed 8 bytes, so we must subtract a further 8 to get back to 16-byte alignment for the call to `__printf_chk`.  The return address is pushed into the stack slot **below** rsp by the call instruction.  The 8 bytes "allocated" by the `sub $8, %rsp` are really never read or written by anybody at all.  Step through the code if you like and you'll see.

Comment: AFAIK the only time when caller's stack is used "implicitly" by a callee is if function arguments are passed on the stack; then the callee can modify them in place.  That is not the case here since we have fewer than 6 arguments, so they are all passed in registers.