# Why is GCC allocating too much stack space for a C array

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, callstack

Consider the following program:

```
int main()
{
   int arr[8];
}
```

When compiling with gcc 9.3.0 on linux 20 the disassembly of the file looks like this at the beginning (this is NOT the whole assembly of the code above!):

```
┌ 72: int dbg.main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
│           ; var int[8] arr @ rbp-0x30
│           ; var int64_t canary @ rbp-0x8
│           0x00001169      f30f1efa       endbr64                     ; test.c:2 { ; int main();
│           0x0000116d      55             push rbp
│           0x0000116e      4889e5         mov rbp, rsp
│           0x00001171      4883ec30       sub rsp, 0x30
```

Why is the assembler allocating 0x30 = 48 bytes on the stack when `arr` is only 8 ints = 8 * 4 bytes long (`sub rsp, 0x30`)?

Comment: What's this "format" your disassembler is talking about?  https://godbolt.org/z/Kq9jzs shows GCC9.3 `-fstack-protector-strong` starting with the instructions you show, but it never accesses `[rbp-0x28]`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that's not the whole asm file, but I'm curious how you got any asm from that C source that a disassembler with partial decompiler features (identifying local vars) would find anything at `rbp-0x28`.  That's the only mystery to me, everything else is normal.  So as Jester commented, it makes me wonder if you actually disassembled a different program that did something with the 8 bytes left after aligning the array below a stack canary.

Comment: From your edit (and deleting your previous comment), I guess that was the case.  The disassembler's comments make sense now.

Comment: Im sorry I just noticed. You were right. The format probably belonged to a printf I deleted from my source file after disassembling. I edited my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's:

- 32 bytes for your array
- 8 bytes for a [stack canary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow#Stack_canaries)
- A further 8 bytes to ensure [16-byte stack alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-the-x86-64-amd64-system-v-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment/49397524#49397524).

Total: 48 bytes.

Comment: But mostly because it's not optimized. Since it is a leaf function it does not need to align the stack, nor does it need any allocation as long as locals fit into the red zone. Also the `format` mentioned in the comment seems to indicate this is assembly for a different program than shown.

Comment: @Jester: For that matter, `arr` could be optimized out altogether; with optimization you just get `xor eax, eax ; ret`.  I found the `format` mysterious because it appears to overlap `arr`.