# Is RSP always a multiple of 16 in GCC at the entry (first intruction) of a function (with default options)?

Tags: gcc, x86-64, memory-alignment, calling-convention

Due to the 16 bytes alignment by default, does this imply the assertion in my question ?

Comment: In short, the answer is yes, assuming you are using the [SysV ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Section 3.2.2: "The end of the input argument area shall be aligned on a 16 byte boundary. In other words, the value
(%rsp + 8) is always a multiple of 16 when control is transferred to
the function entry point.".  That is, `rsp+8` should be a multiple of 16 *before* the call, and the call pushes 8 bytes, so at the entry point `rsp` itself is a multiple of 16.

Comment: Yes, whether the function is reached by tailcall jmp or by an actual call, or anything else, it has to be *as if* it was reached by a call that was done with an aligned RSP.

Comment: It would defeat the purpose of [Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49391001) if you were allowed to enter functions without RSP % 16 == 8.