# Factorial program in x64 assembly always returning 1?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, factorial, att

I'm trying to write a recursive factorial program in x64 assembly. For some reason, no matter what I do, I always get a result of 1. I realize that I don't necessarily need to declare a local variable, but I do it because I'm writing a compiler (for simplicity).

```
.section .data
    outfmt: .asciz "%d\n"
.section .text
    .extern printf
    .global main

fact:
    addq $16, %rsp
    movq %rdi, 0(%rsp)  # Convert parameter to local var.
    movq 0(%rsp), %rax  # Move rdi into rax.
    movq $1, %rbx       # Move 0 into rbx.
    cmp %rax, %rbx      # If rdi <= 1, return 1.
    jle if
    jmp else
else:
    subq $1, 0(%rsp)    # n = n - 1
    call fact           # Call fact
    imulq 0(%rsp), %rax # Multiply n with fact n - 1
    jmp factend
if:
    movq $1, %rax       # Return 1
    jmp factend

factend:
    subq $16, %rsp
    ret

main:
    movq $5, %rdi
    call fact
    movq %rax, %rsi
    leaq outfmt, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call printf
    ret
```

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping the code with a debugger?  What did you learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the bugs I see:

1. You are manipulating the stack backwards.  The stack on x86 grows downwards, so you should subtract from `%rsp` on entry to a function, and add when you return.
2. `cmp %rax, %rbx ; jle if` is backwards.  It will jump to `if` when `rbx <= rax` but you want the other way around, so you probably want `cmp %rbx, %rax`.

   The `Jcc` mnemonics are designed to be intuitive with Intel syntax, where you would write `cmp rax, rbx ; jle if` to jump when `rax <= rbx`.  AT&T reverses the operands of `cmp` like every other instruction, which unfortunately means the conditional jump mnemonics no longer match.
3. You forgot to load the argument into `%rdi` before calling `fact` recursively.  You probably want `movq 0(%rsp), %rdi` if you are going to stick with your scheme of keeping the variable on the stack.
4. Off-by-one error.  You subtract 1 from your variable before calling `fact` recursively, so it is the equivalent of `return (x <= 1) ? 1 :(x-1)*fact(x-1);`.  This mean your program will compute the factorial of 4 instead of 5.
5. You are not maintaining 16-byte stack alignment as required by the SysV ABI (which I assume you are following): [Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-the-x86-64-amd64-system-v-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment)  In particular, you call the library function `printf` with the stack misaligned, which can cause it to crash.  You need to adjust the stack pointer down by 8 bytes in `main` before calling `printf`.  A simple way is to push and pop some register at the beginning and end of `main`.

   You don't maintain stack alignment in `fact` either, but in this case it is harmless since `fact` doesn't call any function except itself.  However if it did, e.g. if you added a `printf` for debugging, you would have problems.
6. The `fact` function clobbers `%rbx` which is specified as call-preserved in the ABI.  This may cause a crash or other misbehavior when `main` returns.