# Segmentation fault when overwriting the return address

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, buffer-overflow

I am stuck on the following problem.
Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void runme() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main(char argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) return 1;
    void (*buffer[8])(void);
    buffer[(int8_t) argv[1][0]] = runme;
    return 0;
}
```

The program reads the first argument, that will serve as an index. If you write the right number you will be able to overwrite the return address, with the address of the function *runme*.

I understand that if I overwrite the return address, when main finish it's execution, the program will continue executing the *runme* function. So with that behaviour in mind, I have calculated which number should I introduce as a first argument.

Then if I try the following command: `./program "$(echo -ne '\x0b')"` the output is **segmentation fault**.
I have tried to debug it in gdb and the output is the following (segfault also):
[image: Gdb output]
In addition, I have looked at dmesg's output, which is the second image.

[image: Dmesg output]

Yesterday I was looking through the internet what could have caused the segmentation fault but I found nothing. What am I missing? Does libc developers have included a new protection mechanism?

My machine information

- Amd Ryzen 5700U
- Ubuntu 22.04
- Gcc 11.03
- Binutils 2.38
- Glibc 2.35

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash is caused by stack misalignment.  See [Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-the-x86-64-amd64-system-v-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment)

The jump-by-ret results in entering `runme` with the stack misaligned, which violates the ABI, and some libc functions do in fact break when called with a misaligned stack.  It doesn't happen on my system, but apparently your `malloc` implementation (which `printf` calls) requires stack alignment.

Disassembling the code bytes, the faulting instruction is `movaps [rsp+0x10], xmm1`, whose memory operand must be aligned to 16 bytes.  However, `rsp` has a hex value ending in `8`, so `rsp+0x10` is not aligned.

I don't off the top of my head see a simple way to have the exploit work around this.

---

Here is a brief explanation of the principle of stack alignment and how it leads to the crash.

It simply means that when the `movaps` instruction is executed, the value in `rsp` is not a multiple of 16 (which is mathematically equivalent to saying that its last hex digit is not 0). The compiler is careful to ensure that it generates code that always adjusts the stack pointer by multiples of 16, such that if it was properly aligned by the caller of this function, then the calls made by this function will also occur with proper alignment.

The rule set out by the x86-64 SysV ABI, which Linux compilers conform to, is that `rsp` must be a multiple of 16 (i.e. must end in 0) when a call instruction is issued.  This means that when the called function begins to execute, then `rsp` is 8 less than a multiple of 16 (i.e. ends in 8), because of the 8-byte return address that was pushed by call. So when `main` reaches its `ret` instruction, with your modified return address on the stack, `rsp` likewise ends in 8 (all stack modification done within `main` has been undone at this point). The `ret` pops the stack once, so you end up at `runme` with `rsp` ending in 0, which is wrong.

This "parity error" propagates down through `printf` and into `malloc`. The `_int_malloc` function expects to be entered with `rsp` ending in 8, so it presumably subtracts an additional 8 bytes (possibly just by pushing) somewhere before executing `movaps`.  As such, `rsp` would end in 0 at that point and all would be well. But since the situation was reversed on entry to `runme`, it stays reversed. `_int_malloc` got entered with `rsp` ending in 0 instead, and so its subtraction of 8 bytes left it *not* ending in 0 when `movaps` executed.

To your comment: At the level of C, stack alignment is the job of the compiler, not the programmer. So a C program can freely define a local array of size 17, and the compiler will then have to know to actually adjust the stack pointer by 32 bytes, leaving the other 15 bytes unused (or using them for other local variables). It isn't something that a C programmer normally has to worry about, but it becomes relevant when you are hacking internals like this.

Comment: Ok, so for me to understand the situation:
When I overwrite the RA, the new function is called. When the CPU executes the code, the stack is not alligned at 16 bytes, so when the CPU hits _int_malloc it causes ath the instruction `movaps [rsp+0x10], xmm1`. What means that the stack is not alligned at 16 bytes is for example, we have an addres such as 0x...B? Or it means that if for example, we have a variable like `char x[17]` is not padded correctly to fill 15 bytes (32 - 17 = 15)?

Comment: @Josep: See edits to question.

Answer (score 0):

That version of the code works "as intended" (between quotes, because, for this kind of code, it depends on who is intending...).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void runme() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main(char argc, char **argv) {
    puts("");
    if (argc != 2) return 1;
    void (*buffer[8])(void);
    buffer[(int8_t) argv[1][0]] = runme;
    return 0;
}
```

The only difference is the `puts`. It works also if you printf anything (but an empty string, but in this case gcc acts as if there were no printf at all).
But not for any function call. For example I've tried with a `fflush(stdout)` at this place, and it is still segfaulting (I've chose this just to be sure that it wasn't a strange thing related to usage of any FILE functions).

### Old answer (unaware that it was on purpose)

What a strange way to pass integer argument.

I was about to reply "`argv[1]`" is a string and cannot be cast to an int, when I saw that you were using `argv[1][0]`, which is an integer (a char). Then to say "you'll get the ascii code of 1st char of whatever argument you pass to your program, which is too big". But even that, you already know, since you pass a specific, non-ascii byte as an argument.

But, well, that byte is `\x0b` which is 11. And you allocate an array of 8 pointer. So, still, it is normal that you have a seg fault.

Comment: Yeah is a weird way, but is an exercise I found on the internet. Anyway, i got a segfault not in main as you can see in the gdb or dmesg picture, so that's what i don't understand.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. Just when I thought "may be he overwrote the return address, and that is why "runme" was called even tho it never was explicitly called", I saw the title of your question (which I already saw at first, but we see some many strange titles around here...), and realized that you did that on purpose (yet, it is still a strange way to pass 11, even if it is voluntarily bigger than 8 :D).

Comment: On my computer, (Ubuntu 20) gcc 9.4, it works as intended. On another computer (Ubuntu 22) on which I copied the binary (without recompiling it) I get the seg fault (and it is not because I did not recompile it locally: it runs without error, returning exit code 1 if I pass no argument, or 0, if I pass a less than 8 byte).

Comment: It could be the version of the libc that includes new checks in the functions that are seen in the gdb backtrace?

Comment: @Josep so apparently, it is not related to gcc version at least.

Comment: No, not gcc. Since it is the same gcc (I compiled it only once. I transfered only the binaray from one machine to the other). So same code, compiled with same gcc; same binary even, runs fine on a machine, and crashes on another.

Comment: I edited the comment, I didn't see at first that you edited your second comment

Comment: It is probaby related to libc, since this occurs inside `printf` (puts, but gcc replace `printf` by `puts` when called without `%thing`)

Comment: Ok thx. I will try on another machine using an older version of ubuntu like yours (It will work, sure).

Comment: Note that if you call printf before, or puts, then it works. See my edit.

Comment: @chrslg: This would be consistent with my guess about stack alignment (see my answer).  If this libc does lazy buffer allocation, then a malloc would occur on the first write to stdout.  So if you write something previously, the `printf` in `runme` doesn't have to allocate a buffer, and so never calls the problematic `malloc`.

Comment: Update: no longer a guess, stack alignment is actually the cause.