# 'sprintf' libc call gives SegFault in assembly on Ubuntu (sometimes)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, libc, calling-convention

I am trying to stringify and integer in assembly (NASM) by making an `sprintf` call.

I have the following assembly code which does this:

```
sprintf_Int_str db "%lld",
                   dq 0
...

Int.str:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp  ; creates stack frame

    ; allocate string
    mov rdi, 64   ; much larger than needed
    call malloc

    push rax ; save char*


    ; write string to allocated memory using `sprintf(buf, "%lld", n)`
    mov rdi, rax
    mov rsi, sprintf_Int_str
    mov rdx, qword [rbp + 16]     ; the location of the number on the stack 
                                  ; (trust me - it's pushed before Int.str is called,
                                  ; meaning it's 2 (64-bit) places before the start 
                                  ; of the stack frame)
    mov rcx, rsi

    mov r8, 0
    mov r9, 0    ; clearing other registers for sake of it
    mov rax, 0   ; (doesn't make a difference if I do this or not)

    call sprintf

    pop rax      ; pop return value which is saved after call to malloc


    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

This code works fine on my machine (Ubuntu 22.10), but I noticed that my automated tests were failing on GitHub Actions (Ubuntu VM).
I set up some tests in Docker to run on my machine, and they worked fine in Alpine, Debian and Arch containers, but again failed in Ubuntu.
I used GDB to analyse the core dump from the failing code, and it gave me this:
[image: core dump]

Which is not very helpful. I've tried all sorts of ways of passing the parameters to `sprintf` as I have seen conflicting info online, but GCC give the following output from the following C++ code:

```c
char* Int_str(int i)
{
    char* str = malloc(64);
    sprintf(str, "%d", i);
    return str;
}
```

```
.LC0:
   .string    "%d"
   .text
   .globl Int_str
   .type  Int_str, @function
Int_str:
   pushq  %rbp
   movq   %rsp, %rbp

   subq   $32, %rsp
   movl   %edi, -20(%rbp)
   movl   $64, %edi
   call   malloc@PLT

   movq   %rax, %rdi
   movl   -20(%rbp), %edx
   leaq   .LC0(%rip), %rcx
   movq   %rcx, %rsi
   movl   $0, %eax
   call   sprintf@PLT

   movq   -8(%rbp), %rax

   leave
   ret
```

which works fine, and seems to be the same as my code, in terms of what registers have what in when `sprintf` is called.

What is particularly puzzling to me is how rarely it fails: always on a Ubuntu VM, never on my Ubuntu machine.
My only idea is that I'm doing something with undefined behavior which happens to always work on my machine due to more RAM or more resilient *something*, but, on the more lightweight VM, that isn't allowed (although adding `--max-ram="1g"` doesn't help).

My assembling command is

```bash
nasm -f elf64 <file.asm> -o out.o
```

And my linking command is

```bash
gcc -Wall -no-pie out.o -e main -o a.out
```

My Ubuntu Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nasm curl build-essential bc

RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

CMD ["/bin/bash", "bin/test"]
```

Which runs a custom bash script (`./bin/test`) which executes the assembly.

Running `ldd --version` on my machine (where it works fine), gives:

`ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.36-0ubuntu4) 2.36`

And running it on the local docker container (where it fais) gives:

`ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35`

But I can't imagine a minor version update would just happen to fix this problem?
Anyway, running `apt install libc-bin` says the package is up to date on both of them.

The repo for my project is here `https://github.com/revers3ntropy/oxynium`, though it has a lot of wrappers around that assembly.

Thanks so much if you can help me!

Comment: `push rax` misaligns the stack. If you examine the faulting instruction e.g. by `x/i $pc` you will probably see it's an instruction requiring alignment.

Comment: I suspect the issue is stack alignment, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-the-x86-64-amd64-system-v-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment.

Comment: Only I don't actually touch the stack after `push rax`... I grab the argument but that is relative to `rbp` and not `rsp` so my push doesn't affect it. On top of this the working C code also doesn't have 'stack alignment', which I would assume means `rsp == rbp`. I have also just tried removing the push and pop (by saving the value in `r15` instead) and that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you check the faulting instruction? No, stack alignment does not mean `rsp == rbp`. Yes, the C code **does** have alignment due to the `subq   $32, %rsp` which is a multiple of 16 while the `push rax` is just 8 bytes which obviously isn't.

Comment: @Jester and @EmployedRussian Thanks so much! I surrounded my libc calls with a new stack frame and `and rsp, -16` and it works everywhere. I don't think I'd ever have figured that out on my own haha. The faulting instruction was something like MOVAPS I think, which does indeed require 16-byte stack alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My only idea is that I'm doing something with undefined behavior

You are. In particular, `x86_64` ABI *requires* that you maintain stack alignment on 16-byte boundary, and you are *not* doing that.

On a machine on which GLIBC is built with `-msse2`, calling into `libc` routines with mis-aligned stack *may* crash.

Examine the crashing instruction (using `x/i $pc` GDB command) -- chances are it's a `MOVDQA` or similar with misaligned source or destination address.