# Is -fstack-usage wrong for leaf functions?

Tags: c, gcc, stack-memory

When I compare the stack usage provided by gcc `-fstack-usage` option of two similar functions, one with a function call and another one without, I have different results.

Let's consider this piece of code:

```c
void donothing(void) {}

void leaf(void) {
    int i = 0;
}

void noleaf(void) {
    int i = 0;
    donothing();
}

int main(void) {
    leaf();
    noleaf();

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to compare the stack usage of `leaf` and `noleaf`. Naively, I would say the stack size is equal for both functions as they have the same local variables. However, when I use `-fstack-usage` option of gcc, I have different results:

```
$ gcc -fstack-usage -o exe leaf.c
$ cat leaf.su 
leaf.c:1:6:donothing    16  static
leaf.c:3:6:leaf         16  static
leaf.c:7:6:noleaf       32  static
leaf.c:12:5:main        16  static
```

We can see that `leaf` has the same stack size than `donothing`. It means that the local variable is not taken into account.

When I look at the assembly code, I can see that the stack is not manipulated the same way between `leaf` and `noleaf`:

```
000000000000112c <leaf>:
    112c:   55                      push   %rbp
    112d:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1130:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    1137:   90                      nop
    1138:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    1139:   c3                      retq   

000000000000113a <noleaf>:
    113a:   55                      push   %rbp
    113b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    113e:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
    1142:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    1149:   e8 d7 ff ff ff          callq  1125 <donothing>
    114e:   90                      nop
    114f:   c9                      leaveq 
    1150:   c3                      retq
```

In `noleaf`, we allocate the space on the stack with `sub    $0x10,%rsp`, but, in `leaf`, the local variable is directly stored on the stack with `movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)` with no "preallocation".

However, even if no "preallocation" is done, the local variable of `leaf` is still on the stack, right? As the stack is also used for the local variable in `leaf`, I would expect to have a stack usage of 32 bytes for this function too. Could I say that the output of `-fstack-usage` is wrong?

---

EDIT: some comments and answers suggest the difference of stack usage is due to `callq` and the alignment requirements. Let's consider a modified version of the source file:

```
void donothing(void) {}

void leaf(void) {
    { int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0; int l = 0; }
    { int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0; int l = 0; }
    { int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0; int l = 0; }
    { int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0; int l = 0; }
}

void noleaf(void) {
    { int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0; int l = 0; }
    { int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0; int l = 0; }
    { int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0; int l = 0; }
    { int i = 0; int j = 0; int k = 0; int l = 0; }
    donothing();
}

int main(void) {
    leaf();
    noleaf();

    return 0;
}
```

If we agree that the difference of stack usage is only explained by the `callq` and the alignment, we should not observe a difference greater than 16 bytes between the two functions. However, here is the results of `-fstack-usage`:

```
su.c:1:6:donothing  16  static
su.c:3:6:leaf       16  static
su.c:10:6:noleaf    80  static
su.c:18:5:main      16  static
```

We can see that `noleaf` uses 80 bytes which seems normal to me (64 bytes for the local variables and 16 bytes for the stack pointers, saved rip and rbp). However, the stack size for `leaf` is still 16 bytes. The local variables are not taken into account.

Here is the assembly code:

```
000000000000112c <leaf>:
    112c:   55                      push   %rbp
    112d:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1130:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    1137:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
    113e:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%rbp)
    1145:   c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)
    114c:   c7 45 ec 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x14(%rbp)
    1153:   c7 45 e8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
    115a:   c7 45 e4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x1c(%rbp)
    1161:   c7 45 e0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
    1168:   c7 45 dc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x24(%rbp)
    116f:   c7 45 d8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x28(%rbp)
    1176:   c7 45 d4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x2c(%rbp)
    117d:   c7 45 d0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x30(%rbp)
    1184:   c7 45 cc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x34(%rbp)
    118b:   c7 45 c8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x38(%rbp)
    1192:   c7 45 c4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x3c(%rbp)
    1199:   c7 45 c0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x40(%rbp)
    11a0:   90                      nop
    11a1:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    11a2:   c3                      retq   

00000000000011a3 <noleaf>:
    11a3:   55                      push   %rbp
    11a4:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    11a7:   48 83 ec 40             sub    $0x40,%rsp
    11ab:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
    11b2:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
    11b9:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%rbp)
    11c0:   c7 45 f0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)
    11c7:   c7 45 ec 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x14(%rbp)
    11ce:   c7 45 e8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
    11d5:   c7 45 e4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x1c(%rbp)
    11dc:   c7 45 e0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
    11e3:   c7 45 dc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x24(%rbp)
    11ea:   c7 45 d8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x28(%rbp)
    11f1:   c7 45 d4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x2c(%rbp)
    11f8:   c7 45 d0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x30(%rbp)
    11ff:   c7 45 cc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x34(%rbp)
    1206:   c7 45 c8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x38(%rbp)
    120d:   c7 45 c4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x3c(%rbp)
    1214:   c7 45 c0 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x40(%rbp)
    121b:   e8 05 ff ff ff          callq  1125 <donothing>
    1220:   90                      nop
    1221:   c9                      leaveq 
    1222:   c3                      retq
```

Therefore, I think the `callq` statement is not enough to explain the difference of stack usage between the two functions.

Comment: Does it make any sense to analyze -O0 stack usage. Enable optimizations and you will much more logical results. (ion this trivial example zero everywhere)

Comment: @0___________ IMO looking analyzing `-O0` (no optimisation) code makes sense for educational purposes.

Comment: @0___________ I prefer to not use any optimization to understand the behavior of `-fstack-usage`. However, I agree this is not a real-case example.

Comment: I think it's because the stack needs to be 16 bytes aligned before `callq` on x64. See [Why does the x86-64 / AMD64 System V ABI mandate a 16 byte stack alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-the-x86-64-amd64-system-v-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment). If you build with `-m32`, it'll the same value.

Comment: @couyoh I do not think alignment is enough to explain the difference of stack usage between the two functions. See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples shown are consistent with GCC counting each routine as using 16 bytes (the stack frame used to call it, including the initial `push %rbp` in each routine) plus the amount by which it decrements the stack pointer.

Use of the red zone (the portion of the stack that may be used but is below where `%rsp` points) is not counted.

This is a reasonable accounting method since the total change in `%rsp` between the initial start routine and any other routine will equal the sum of the stack use GCC reports for each of the routines in the call stack.